# premature eof error in flex file

Tags: c, bison, lexical-analysis, flex-lexer

I have the following code and it gives an error" "hello.l",line 31: premature EOF" when I run the following command
flex hello.l

```
%{

  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include "y.tab.h"

  %}

%%

("hi"|"oi")"\n"      {return HI; }
("tchau"|"bye")"\n"  {return BYE;}
.                    {yyerror(); }

%%

int main(void)
{
    yyparse();
    return 0;
}

int yywrap(void)
{
    return 0;
}

int yyerror(void)
{
    printf("Error\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The problem is with your `%}` - flex is *very* sensitive about spacing. Remove the space before it, and all should be well.

Also, if you don't want a yywrap function, you can stick `%option noyywrap` in your flex file.

Comment: Can you tell me how to run compile both lex.yy.c and y.tab.c files in dev-C++ ?

Answer (score 7):

Change this:

```
%{

  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include "y.tab.h"

  %}
```

To this:

```
%{

  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include "y.tab.h"

%}
```

It works with flex 2.5.35 (mingw)